# "Property $notify does not exist on type" - Can't use npm package on Vue App

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [this npm package](https://github.com/euvl/vue-notification) to send notifications in my Vue App. After following the instructions, and adding the required usages on the `main.ts`, I keep getting when I try to use the features of it:

```
    Property '$notify' does not exist on type 'Shop'
```

**main.ts**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Notifications from 'vue-notification'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.use(Notifications)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Character from "./Character.vue";
import Vendor from "./Vendor.vue";

@Component<Shop>({
  components: {
    Character,
    Vendor
  },
})
export default class Shop extends Vue {
  sellItem(itemID) {
    this.$notify({
      title: 'Important message',
      text: 'Hello user!'
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried importing the component in the .vue file, however it does not recognize the type. What am I doing wrong? I can't find any solution for this...

Thank you.

Comment: Try `Vue.notify` from the component context

Comment: @apokryfos I forgot to mention that I also tried to call it with that, but get `Property 'notify' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'.Vetur(2339)` this.

Comment: Make sure the file `main.ts` is imported as well or do `Vue.use` again

Comment: @Layan I cannot reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-notification-demo). What tool is reporting that error?

Answer (score 0):

**Add a shim typings file**

You need a file that imports and re-exports the type of "Vue", it is named vue-file-import.d.ts, but elsewhere on the internet it is commonly called vue-shim.d.ts. Regardless of name, the content needed is the same:

```
// vue-file-import.d.ts

declare module "*.vue" {
   import Vue from "vue";
   export default Vue;
}
```

Try placing the above file in  `/src` location. But sometimes when you move around changing things it might not work so I suggest you to place it inside `/typings` location

Comment: Mine is a .Vue Single Component File, even if I try that, however, I get the same message: 'Property 'notify' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'.Vetur(2339)'

Comment: I found this file on the src folder: `shims-vue.d.ts` with that code inside, so I assume that is already done? This is a boilerplate, I did not set it up myself.

Comment: As I said move it to `/typings` location and check

Comment: I'm not sure  have that on my project... Also I do not fully know what /typings is. I'm sorry.